# Firebase Security: read-only parent node, but writable child nodes

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Can I have a read-only parent node, but allow write to its leaf node?

Use-case:

User parent 
Testimonial as children

I'd let authenticated user to read their own user object, but allow them write testimonials to other user.

Or shoud it be down as two parent level nodes with user id linked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can.

Setup the more restrictive .write rule at the parent rule, but then setup a less restrictive .write rule at the leaf node.

For example:

```
{
   "root": {
       "parent": {
            "$user": {
                 ".write": false,
                 ".read": true,                    
                 "leaf": {
                     ".write": true
                 }
             }
       }
}
```

Comment: How is leaf writeble if .write was denied at the $user(parent of leaf) level?

Comment: @Relm because of the way security rules inheritance works. The leaf level .write = true overrides the inherited parent node .write = false.

It's similar to setting up restrictive read/write rules at `root`. You don't want to allow people to blindly write/delete all of your structures, so you typically deny read/write to `root`, but you open up access to specific areas lower down in your data tree.